# M-x compile --> emacs doesn't automatically open files

Tags: compilation, compilation-mode

I have recently switched from an older version of emacs to version 24.3.1. And I have run into the following problem: I have a base folder "/base" and a folder with source files "base/src"; my makefile is in "/base".

When I run "M-x compile" in the /base/src folder with the compilation option "-C ../" and get some compilation error such as

```
src/XXX.f90(578): error #6457: This derived type name has not been declared.   [my_type]
```

emacs conveniently lets me click on the file name to track down the error. Now, it used to be that I would click on "src/XXX.f90(578):" and emacs would automatically open the corresponding file in "/base/src/XXX.f90".

However, with the new version I get an additional message

```
Find this error in (default src/XXX.f90): /base/src
```

Where I apparently need to complete the file path and hit enter for emacs to open the file.

It seems to work as usual, when I first switch to /base and then hit "M-x compile" without the "-C ../" option. So my guess would be that emacs somehow no longer treats the relative paths correctly?

Does someone maybe know how to help emacs along and find the files the way it used to when compile with "-C ../" command in folder '/base/src'?

Thanks a lot in advance for your suggestions.